# An MVVM button event with a list view not getting the selected item

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, mvvm-toolkit

I am trying to get the selectedItem from my list view. I am using MVVM light toolkit and the EventToCommand on a button.

My listView is bound to an ObservableCollection which is correctly binding. Here is the listView xaml:

```
  <ListView   Name="serverListView"
                    Grid.Row="3"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Servers}"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ServerList}"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    BorderThickness="0"/>
```

I then have a button which I am using Interaction.Triggers with a mvvm EventToCommand, I am not sure if the selectedItem binding is correct. The event is firing correctly through a Relay Command (mvvm light toolkit) but I am getting null every time.

Here is my button xaml;

```
<Button x:Name="LoadButton"
                Content="Load Server"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="4"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <mvvm:EventToCommand  Command="{Binding ButtonClick, Mode=OneWay}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=serverListView}"
                                            MustToggleIsEnabledValue="True"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
```

Relay Command:

```
 this.ButtonClick = new RelayCommand<object>(new Action<object>(this.GetClickEvent));
```

Comment: why do you need an eventtocommand behavior over here? just use the button´s Command/CommandParameter properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should as well bind the SelectedItem property of the listview to a property (SelectedServer) of your viewmodel, and change your EventToCommand

```
CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=serverListView}"
```

to

```
CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedServer}"
```

Answer (score 1):

get rid of the commandparameter binding, create a SelectedServer property in your viewmodel and the Command in your viewmodel without parameter

```
<ListView   Name="serverListView"
                Grid.Row="3"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Servers}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ServerList}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedServer}"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                BorderThickness="0"/>

<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
```

in your viewmodel you have all information you need to do your command logic.